# Yii2 AssetBundle convert less file but don't publish

Tags: yii2, assets

I have a widget where I wanted to convert a less file to an css file. 
The conversion works perfectly. But now I want that the less files aren't published to the `web/assets` directory.
*And here the Pain begins...*

This is my code:

```
class BreadcrumbsAsset extends  \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $css = [
        'css/breadcrumbs.less',
    ];

    public $js = [
        'js/breadcrumbs.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public $publishOptions = [
        "only" => [
            "css/*",
            "js/*",
        ],
        'except' => [
            "doc/",
            "*.less",
        ],
    ];
}
```

But with the `except` setting set the css file isn't generated. 
Also when I try the other way around and set:

```
public $publishOptions = [
    "only" => [
        "css/*.css",
    ],
```

**The css file isn't generated from the less file any more.
So how does this supose to work?**

When the to options `only` and `except` are added for this this case:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2511 (AssetBundle should not publish .less or .coffee files)

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8566 (AssetManager support for choosing file/dir to be publish)

The Publishoptions are descriped like this:

> - only: array, list of patterns that the file paths should match if they want to be copied.
> - except: array, list of patterns that the files or directories should match if they want to be excluded from being copied.

And in the Filehelper which is used for the File Publish the `except` and `only` are descriped like this (from the Yii2 Filehelper Source):

```
- `except`: array, list of patterns excluding from the results matching file or directory paths.
  Patterns ending with slash ('/') apply to directory paths only, and patterns not ending with '/'
  apply to file paths only. For example, '/a/b' matches all file paths ending with '/a/b';
  and `.svn/` matches directory paths ending with `.svn`.
  If the pattern does not contain a slash (`/`), it is treated as a shell glob pattern
  and checked for a match against the pathname relative to `$dir`.
  Otherwise, the pattern is treated as a shell glob suitable for consumption by `fnmatch(3)`
  `with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a `/` in the pathname.
  For example, `views/*.php` matches `views/index.php` but not `views/controller/index.php`.
  A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, `/*.php` matches `index.php` but not `views/start/index.php`.
  An optional prefix `!` which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.
  If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources. Put a backslash (`\`) in front of the first `!`
  for patterns that begin with a literal `!`, for example, `\!important!.txt`.
  Note, the '/' characters in a pattern matches both '/' and '\' in the paths.

- `only`: array, list of patterns that the file paths should match if they are to be returned. Directory paths
  are not checked against them. Same pattern matching rules as in the `except` option are used.
  If a file path matches a pattern in both `only` and `except`, it will NOT be returned.
```

**So how should this `only` and `except` settings work?
Or is this a Bug?**

*Forgot to mention that of course I have the newest yii2 version installed (the only and except settings for publishOptions were introduced with yii 2.0.6)*

Comment: `only` and `except` options work before converting is done so if you exclude the file to convert it will not be processed obviously. I'm not sure but the only way may be to extend AssetConverter to remove `less` file after converting.

Comment: But this 2 options where explicitly mentioned here that this was fixed with 2.06 https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2511#issuecomment-207736601
and this was added: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/8a506e1ee3f4ce2e1d66e93fb54814475d65ae09

Comment: This does not look like properly fixed issue. `less` file is still present. It's good you've reopened it, maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: I guess these except and only options only work whenn the less files aren't in the css folder. So that the complete folder could be excluded. E.g. if the css files are generated externally by grunt or perhapts via the console asset controller.
It would be good if those except is only handled for publish and not also for the convertion.

Comment: No, options work no matter what file is there. The problem here is the order of processing like I said in first comment.

Comment: `publishOptions`: specifies the options that will be passed to the `yii\web\AssetManager::publish()` method when it is called to publish source asset files to a Web directory. **This is only used if you specify the `sourcePath` property.**